# mysqli prepare() is returning a boolean true instead of a statement object

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, return

I've seen this issue all over the internet but none of the solutions for others have fixed my errors.  I have the following PHP code:

```
  $err = false;
  $mysqli = getMysqlConnection();
  if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, regtime, emailverified, type) values (?,?,?,?,?);"))
  {
      date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
      $dateStr = date("m-d-Y h:i:s");
      $emailverified = 0;
      $type = 0;

      $stmt->bind_param('sssii', $username, $email, $dateStr, $emailverified, $type);
      $rc = $stmt->execute();
      $err = $rc ? $err : true;

      $userId = $stmt->insert_id;    

      if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO usercreds (user_id, username, hash) VALUES (?,?,?);") && $err === false)
      {
          //
          //right here, for some reason, $stmt is true (boolean), not an object
          //

          $stmt->bind_param('iss', $userId, $username, $hash);
          $rc = $stmt->execute();
          $err = $rc ? $err : true;
      }
      else {
        $err = true;
      }
  }
```

The first query runs without problems, but the second query breaks on the call to bind_params.  I get the error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean

This means (and I have confirmed) that the second time I do `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare()`, it's returning a boolean rather than an object.  Furthermore, it's returning true, which I find very strange.

I have quadruple checked my query, and it is perfectly fine and valid.  Yet for some reason the second time I try to prepare a statement he prepare method returns a boolean instead of a statement object.

Another note, echoing out $mysqli->error after the second prepare() outputs nothing.

How do I resolve this issue?

---

**Afterthought:**

Part of me feels like this is because I'm using the same mysqli object twice in a row? or maybe because I'm using the same statement object twice in a row?  Is there some sort of "shutting down" or "resetting" of one of these objects that needs to take place in order to execute a second query?

**Another edit:**

Additional proof that my second query is valid.  I copied and pasted it and replaced the ?'s with values, executed it in mysql workbench, and it ran perfectly fine.

```
INSERT INTO usercreds (user_id, username, hash) VALUES (1234567890,'testusr','hashhashhash');
```

Comment: Pop this at the top of your script ~ `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: Oh, the problem is you're assigning a boolean value to `$stmt` via `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(...) && $err === false`. Maybe try `if (!$err && $stmt = $mysqli->prepare(...))`

Comment: @Phil Holy crap that was it!  I moved that $err check to the front and it's working!  I didn't even think of that.

Comment: Use the line in my first comment to make *mysqli* throw exceptions and never have to check the result of method calls for `false` ever again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by **essentially wrong way of error handling**. That is, beside producing errors, is making your code bloat.

Below is the only code you really need:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
// below is the only line you need for the error handling
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = getMysqlConnection();

$dateStr = date("m-d-Y h:i:s");
$emailverified = 0;
$type = 0;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, regtime, emailverified, type) values (?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssii', $username, $email, $dateStr, $emailverified, $type);
$stmt->execute();
$userId = $mysqli->insert_id;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO usercreds (user_id, username, hash) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('iss', $userId, $username, $hash);
$stmt->execute();
```

The rest is depends on what you going to do in case of error.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the result of `$mysqli->prepare(..) && $err === false` to `$stmt`. That is a boolean expression. You want either of these variations:

```
if (($stmt = $mysqli->prepare(...)) && $err === false)
if ($err === false && $stmt = $mysqli->prepare(...))
```